# native IPv6 setup

Tags: networking, ipv6

I got following information from my provider:

```
Range: 2a00:1630:2:801::/64
Gateway: 2a00:1630:2:800::1
Netmask: /56
```

My config file:

```
iface eth0 inet6 static
address
netmask 56
gateway 2a00:1630:2:800::1
dns-nameservers 2620:0:ccc::2
up ip -6 addr add 2a00:1630:2:801::/64 dev eth0
```

Are these settings correct and what do I have to put at *address*? Also what does the netmask 56 mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `/56` means that the first 56 bits of the address prefix are fixed, and that you can use the other 128 - 56 = 72 bits yourself. In IPv6 a subnet is always a `/64` (except if you have a good reason to do otherwise and you really know what you are doing). That means that you have 64 - 56 = 8 bits to create multiple subnets. With prefix `2a00:1630:2:800::/56` that means you can use subnets `2a00:1630:2:800::/64` to `2a00:1630:2:8ff::/64`.

You don't explain how your network is connected. I'll explain how it usually works. You do specify that the default gateway is at `2a00:1630:2:800::1`. That means that all devices that want to talk to that default gateway have to be in `2a00:1630:2:800::/64`, at least on the network interface that connects towards that default gateway. If you connect a router or firewall then that device can have (for example) address `2a00:1630:2:800::2` on the interface towards the default gateway, and `2a00:1630:2:801::1` on the interface for the local LAN.

From the IPv6 address range I see that this is the i3D network. If this is a hosting network in a data centre, it might be that they did something non-standard (which I have seen more often in such networks). For example, I have seen hosting networks where they put a whole `/48` or `/56` on one LAN, which I really don't understand. A standard `/64` already contains 18,446,744,073,709,551,616 addresses. Why would they deviate from the standard to make the number 65,536 or 256 times as large? Not to mention the potential instability of such a large layer-2 domain.

Anyway, if they did something silly like this then something like this might work:

```
iface eth0 inet6 static
    address 2a00:1630:2:801::1
    netmask 56
    gateway 2a00:1630:2:800::1
    dns-nameservers 2620:0:ccc::2
    post-up ip -6 addr add 2a00:1630:2:801::abcd/64 dev eth0 
    post-up ip -6 addr add 2a00:1630:2:801:c001:cafe:babe:1/64 dev eth0
```

The post-up lines add extra IPv6 addresses to the interface.

In that case they mean to say the the LAN uses a non-standard `/56` and they allow you to use the addresses in `2a00:1630:2:801::/64`. The other `/64`s in the `/56` presumably belong to other customers on that LAN.

Comment: Thank you for this detailed answer. Your configuration works. I still have a question, can I install the hole subnet at one time? So I can use all address from _2a00:1630:2:800::/64_ to _2a00:1630:2:8ff::/64_

Comment: If you want to use multiple addresses then you'll have to configure them. As far as I know it is not possible to make it listen to all addresses in a subnet in one go.

Comment: If your provider is giving you the whole `/56` then you can use every address in the range you specified. If they did the silly thing then you could technically use every address in that range, but they probably want you to stick to `2a00:1630:2:801::/64` (bsed on what you have shown). You'd have to ask them to be sure.

Comment: Oh well I looked around Google but I couldn't find a working example on how to add several other IPs to the interface. I have tried to copy the config from you and replaced _eth0_ with _eth0:0_ and _address_ with other IP but it didn't work.

Comment: I added some examples for multiple addresses

Comment: When I add the first additional IP it throws me an error: _RTNETLINK answers: File exists Filed to bring up eth0_